# Arduino IDE crashes in Gentoo

Tags: java, arduino, ide

A few days before, I installed arduino-ide in Gentoo from this overlay: https://github.com/maurerpe/arduino-overlay

The installation was successfull, but when I try to run it, it crashes and shows that error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionsIndex: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.FileInputStream@62fdb4a6; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2908)
    at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionsIndexer.parseIndex(ContributionsIndexer.java:173)
    at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionsIndexer.parseIndex(ContributionsIndexer.java:84)`
```

I tried to change Java VM, but the error continues.
I've tried with Icedtea 7, Oracle JRE 8 and Oracle JDK 8

Do you know how can I fix that error?

Update: After reemerged Oracle JRE 8 with flag commercial and javafx enabled, the Arduino IDE downloaded from oficial web feels run well.
But the arduino-ide emerged from the overlay continues failing

Comment: @nhouser9 tks for the edit

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch in the Java libraries somewhere.

Comment: @chrylis could arduino-ide needs java 6?

Comment: It's not the JDK, it's the Java packages that make up the Arduino IDE. Gentoo is kinda notorious for letting dependencies get out of sync.

Comment: @chrylis Then... I need install any unknown dependency